# Draw a diagram like this one

Tags: java, javascript, spring

Does anybody have an idea what tools can be used to draw a diagram like the following?

[image]

Sectors correspond with some parameters - sector 1 for parameter 1 etc. 
As you can see, each sector is divided into "levels", and there are "colors" to designate which level is acceptable. Parameter values are not necesserily "discrete" - see parameter 20.

Project details: Using spring-mvc, javascript and some jquery magic.

What I need: presumably, some tool (framework, library etc) that will generate diagram based on my values. Diagram should be saved in graphical format (jpeg, ...) for further usage (export to doc, display on the web-page)

PS. Even if you can propose a method that will not generate EXACTLY the same diagram, I would be much grateful to you..

Comment: A graphing library of sorts would be able to do something like this.

Comment: I've made this kind of charts before, look at the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Y4r/1/), I just tweaked to look similar to yours

Answer (score 4):

This would be possible to do with the [D3.js library](http://d3js.org/).

Check [this blog](http://kreese.net/blog/2012/08/26/d3-js-creating-a-polar-area-diagram-radial-bar-chart/) where the author has created something similar with D3.js

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do that would be using an SVG object. SVG is a format for vector graphics which can be embedded into HTML documents and which can be manipulated with Javascript (add/remove/change shapes, change the color of shapes).

When you have any **specific** questions, feel free to write a new question.